# How to save the Id descending in the database with code-first?

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, code-first

I want to save the Id as a **descending** order in the table
with use **code-first**

But I do not know how

My Model:

```
public class AccountChangeHistory
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```